# Handling Multiple JavaScript Replace Matches

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following string:

```
This *is* a *test*!
```

I want to bold the words surrounded by the * characters (so "is" and "test" in the example).

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var data = "This *is* a *test*!";
return data.replace(/\*(.*)\*/g, <b>$1</b>);
```

When the string is returned, I get the following:

```
This <b>is* a *test</b>!
```

How can I change the pattern or basic code in order to do the replacement the way I want it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SO messed with my HTML...

```
var result = "This *is* a *test*!".replace(/\*(.*?)\*/gi, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Comment: You don't really need the `i` modifier in this example - `.*` will match anything upper or lower case, and `\*` isn't affected by case.

Comment: This is much harder to do if the text comes from the user (and not the system), since to avoid XSS attacks means either heavy whitelist sanitisation, or need to use a technique that doesn't involve strings of HTML (e.g. use DOM API instead).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the pattern non-greedy by adding the ?-operator after the *:

```
var data = "This *is* a *test*!";
return data.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Here is a reference for JavaScript RegExp from [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).